# Maximum fractional chromatic number of a 4-regular triangle-free graph (updated)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a graph with maximum degree 4 and clique number 2.  The fractional version of Reed's Conjecture tells us that $\chi_f(G) \leq 7/2$.  But how high can $\chi_f(G)$ be?

The Chvátal graph has fractional chromatic number 3.  The [Grünbaum graph on 25 vertices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GruenbaumGraphs.html) has stability number 8, and therefore has fractional chromatic number at least $25/8$.

**Update:** The graph pictured below, from ["A note on 4-regular 4 chromatic graphs with girth 4"](http://math.nju.edu.cn/~zkmfl/kmzhang/41-60/Zhang44.pdf) by Song, Wang, Yao, and Zhang, has stability number 4 and 13 vertices, and therefore has fractional chromatic number at least $13/4$; Nathann Cohen provided a proof that indeed $\chi_f=13/4$ for this graph.

> Let $z$ be the maximum fractional chromatic number of a triangle-free graph with maximum degree 4.  Then
>   $$
> \frac{13}{4} \leq z \leq \frac{14}4.
> $$
>   Are better bounds possible?

[image: Worst case?]